# Why only first page results get exported to csv?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, ransack, kaminari

I am trying to get **ALL** the filtered results when exporting to CSV.

My `to_csv` is working fine, and I suspect something to do with my controller.

Search around with kaminari, ransack, but seems like even exporting to csv is rare using ransack.
Any help is much appreciated.

**controller.rb**

```
@search = Order.includes(:user, :order_items).ransack(params[:q])
@orders = @search.result.order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page])

respond_to do  
  |format|
  format.html
  format.csv { send_data @orders.to_csv, filename: "orders-#{DateTime.now.strftime("%d%m%Y%H%M")}.csv" }
end
```

**view.html.haml**

```
= link_to 'Download as CSV', a_o_path(request.params.merge(format: 'csv')), { class: 'btn btn-primary', style: 'float: right;' }
```

Comment: You are merging the request params right? So the q params will get submitted as well, resulting in Ransack performing the search before rendering the csv. Why don't you just call: `a_o_path(:format => :csv)`

Comment: @bo-oz Sorry, that did not seem to work. Request merge is to get the filtered results.

Comment: Yes, but you need to get rid of the parameters that are causing kaminari to kick in. If you'd debug the call to the controller methiod, you'd see that @orders contains only first x orders, due to pagination. That then gets passed to the csv view. You get exactly what you ask for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with ransack and kaminari, but you'll need to update your controller just a bit. Here's what you have so far:

```
format.csv { send_data @orders.to_csv, filename: "orders-#{DateTime.now.strftime("%d%m%Y%H%M")}.csv" }
```

When your controller gets here, `@orders` has been filtered by ransack, but it has also been paginated by kaminari. Since you're responding with html in some cases and csv in others, you'll want to do something slightly different when you respond with csv.

Here's what I would try:

```
@search = Order.includes(:user, :order_items).ransack(params[:q])
@orders = @search.result.order(created_at: :desc)

respond_to do |format|
  format.html { @orders = @orders.page(params[:page]) }
  format.csv { send_data @orders.to_csv, filename: "orders-#{DateTime.now.strftime("%d%m%Y%H%M")}.csv" }
end
```

Basically, you only paginate the query when you respond with html. When csv is requested, all of the orders will still be there.